# Proper URL forming with a query string and an anchor hashtag

Tags: php, wordpress, url, standards, url-fragment

When both a query string and anchor tag (hash tag) are visible in a URL, what is the proper order for them to appear?

`http://www.whatever.com?var=val#anchor`

or

`http://www.whatever.com#anchor?var=val`

Is there any documentation on this?

The URLs are being handled by WordPress / PHP.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

```
?var=var#hash
```

Everything after `#` is client side.

Also, look into [URL rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) to get rid of ugly `?var=var`.

Comment: query string is ugly but it has its purpose and is more flexible

Comment: What's wrong with using query strings? they are part of the HTTP standard for a reason

Comment: Yes, but for SPAs (Single Page Applications), what parameters for client-side page-to-page parameters?

Answer (score 131):

**? should come before the #** as noted in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1):

```
relative-ref = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

*Taken from an answer over at Super User (*[Does an anchor tag come before the query string or after?](https://superuser.com/questions/498617/does-an-anchor-tag-come-before-the-query-string-or-after)*):*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It clearly points out the documentation and is void of the comentator's personal opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Note that when the URL has both anchor tags (#) and query strings (?), the browser may ignore the query string and navigate to the anchor tag without reloading the page.

It may be necessary to submit the page using a

```html
<form action='webpage.php?q=string#tag' method='GET or POST'>
    <input type='text' id='q' name='q' value='string'>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

rather than just a URL link

```html
<a href='webpage.php?q=string#tag'>.
```

Comment: Is it literally `method='GET or POST'>`? Shouldn't it be just POST? Why not?

Comment: OK, user *Teacher Michael* has left the building. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?

Answer (score 5):

If the intention of using `#` is to denote a [page `fragment` then](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16) - yes `?` and then `#`.

If `#` is coming before `?` and it is not to denote a page `fragment` (this can happen when `#` is part of authority (username and password)) it has to be encoded or you are in trouble. The same applies to any other special characters (`:`,`@`,...) that could give a different meaning to the URL.

Answer (score 3):

You may place this JavaScript code in the common part of your site to force redirecting all incorrect requests to the analog with proper order:

```html
<script>
    var p=location.hash.indexOf("?");
    if(p>=0){
        var goodLoc = location.href.replace(location.hash, "");
        location.replace(goodLoc + window.location.hash.substring(p) + window.location.hash.substring(0, p));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"to the analog"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I mean the URL with the same parts but in proper order.
`http://www.whatever.com?var=val#anchor `
instead of 
`http://www.whatever.com#anchor?var=val`