# function to retrieve url variables using javascript and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my script there a simple list shows links for editing

```
<ul>
<li><a href="edit.php?id=5" class="edit">click here</a></li>
<li><a href="edit.php?id=5" class="edit">click here</a></li>
<li><a href="edit.php?id=5" class="edit">click here</a></li>
<li><a href="edit.php?id=5" class="edit">click here</a></li>
</ul>
```

what i need is to read the variable id so i can send it through .ajax call and i tried this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1)
                                         .split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
     }
     $('.edit').click(function(){
         var test = getUrlVars()["id"];
         alert(test);
     });
});
```

When I clicked on the link, the alert message shows `undefined`.

I tried another function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urlParams = {};
    (function () {
        var match,
               pl = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
           search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
           decode = function(s) { 
               return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); 
           },
           query  = window.location.search.substring(1);
           while (match = search.exec(query))
               urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
     })();
     $('.edit').click(function(){
         var test = urlParams["id"];
         alert(test);
     });
 });
```

... but even this also shows up the alert message `undefined`.

Comment: `vars.push(hash[0]); vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];` - what for, why do you try to process `vars` both like an array and like an object?

Comment: Precisely @raina77ow - I just reviewed a piece of code that was trying to use this function, and I noticed the same thing. Bad code bites even after 4 years I suppose ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The methods your tried don't take an URL as argument, but parse the current URL parameters** (i.e. the URL within your brother). Just modify the first method like this to make it work:

```
$(function() {
    function getUrlVars(url) {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
    $('.edit').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var test = getUrlVars(href)["id"];
        alert(test);
    });
});
```

Side note: you could also modify the second one, both of them do the same job.

Comment: As everything after the hash (#) is client side (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683131) the var "hashes" should be updated to ignore the task symbol #. Suggested: `var url_split_hashtags = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('#'); var hashes = url_split_hashtags[0].split('&');`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

### JavScript

```js
function getUrlParams() {
    var params = {};
    location.search.replace(/\?/g, '').split('&').forEach(function(item) {
      params[item.split('=')[0]] = item.split('=')[1];
    });
    return params;
}
```

#### The function will return an object like this:

```js
{
  firstName: 'Jordan',
  lastName: 'Belfort',
  position: 'The Wolf of Wall Street',
}
```

#### Usage

```js
var urlParams = getUrlParams();
alert('Hello ' + urlParams.firstName + ' ' + urlParams.lastName);
```

**Note:** There's actually no need to use location.href and split the url at '?', since we can get the whole query string with `location.search`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your problem, why not put the `id` part of the `href` into a `data` parameter and read that? It would save you having to dissect the URL. Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="edit.php?id=5" data-id="5" class="edit">click here</a></li>
    <li><a href="edit.php?id=6" data-id="6" class="edit">click here</a></li>
    <li><a href="edit.php?id=7" data-id="7" class="edit">click here</a></li>
    <li><a href="edit.php?id=8" data-id="8" class="edit">click here</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.edit').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: i used to test in http://jsfiddle.net/ and just work fine but in my script it doesn't work i don't know why ?

Comment: @Dr.Neo are you using the HTML5 doctype? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function getParameterByName( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right the first time, you just have to declare `vars` as object and get rid of `vars.push(...)`.

Here's working example - http://jsfiddle.net/KN9aK/1/show/?id=yoursuperduperid

Source here http://jsfiddle.net/KN9aK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change it to use an object, not an array.

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {}, //<--object
    hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1)
                                     .split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];  //<--add to the object
    }
    return vars;  //<--return the object
 }
```

Also you can use `window.location.search` so you do not have to do that initial slice.