# AJAX Product Filtering fires twice when clicking on button

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm building an WP online Shop with an [Ajax Filtering Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-ajax-product-filter/) which filters the products by category and so on. When I click a category button it requests the URL twice, as if the function is executed twice. I checked the behavior with the firebug console - it requests the URL twice. Any help would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// return false if wcapf_params variable is not found
if (typeof wcapf_params === 'undefined') {
    return false;
}

// store widget ids those will be replaced with new data
var widgets = {};

$('.wcapf-ajax-term-filter').each(function(index) {
    var widget_id = $(this).attr('id');
    widgets[index] = widget_id;
});

// scripts to run before updating shop loop
wcapfBeforeUpdate = function() {
    var overlay_color;
    
    if (wcapf_params.overlay_bg_color.length) {
        overlay_color = wcapf_params.overlay_bg_color;
    } else {
        overlay_color = '#fff';
    }

    var markup = '<div class="wcapf-before-update" style="background-color: ' + overlay_color + '"></div>',
        holder,
        top_scroll_offset = 0;

    if ($(wcapf_params.shop_loop_container.length)) {
        holder = wcapf_params.shop_loop_container;
    } else if ($(wcapf_params.not_found_container).length) {
        holder = wcapf_params.not_found_container;
    }

    if (holder.length) {
        // show loading image
        $(markup).prependTo(holder);

        // scroll to top
        if (typeof wcapf_params.scroll_to_top !== 'undefined' && wcapf_params.scroll_to_top == true) {
            var scroll_to_top_offset,
                top_scroll_offset;

            if (typeof wcapf_params.scroll_to_top_offset !== 'undefined' && wcapf_params.scroll_to_top_offset.length) {
                scroll_to_top_offset = parseInt(wcapf_params.scroll_to_top_offset);
            } else {
                scroll_to_top_offset = 100;
            }

            top_scroll_offset = $(holder).offset().top - scroll_to_top_offset;
            
            if (top_scroll_offset < 0) {
                top_scroll_offset = 0;
            }

            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: top_scroll_offset}, 'slow');        
        }
    }

}

// scripts to run after updating shop loop
wcapfAfterUpdate = function() {}

// load filtered products
wcapfFilterProducts = function() {
    // run before update function: show a loading image and scroll to top
    wcapfBeforeUpdate();

    $.get(window.location.href, function(data) {
        var $data = jQuery(data),
            shop_loop = $data.find(wcapf_params.shop_loop_container),
            not_found = $data.find(wcapf_params.not_found_container);

        // replace widgets data with new data
        $.each(widgets, function(index, id) {
            var single_widget = $data.find('#' + id),
                single_widget_class = $(single_widget).attr('class');

            // update class
            $('#' + id).attr('class', single_widget_class);
            // update widget
            $('#' + id).html(single_widget.html());
        });

        // replace old shop loop with new one
        if (wcapf_params.shop_loop_container == wcapf_params.not_found_container) {
            $(wcapf_params.shop_loop_container).html(shop_loop.html());
        } else {
            if ($(wcapf_params.not_found_container).length) {
                if (shop_loop.length) {
                    $(wcapf_params.not_found_container).html(shop_loop.html());
                } else if (not_found.length) {
                    $(wcapf_params.not_found_container).html(not_found.html());
                }
            } else if ($(wcapf_params.shop_loop_container).length) {
                if (shop_loop.length) {
                    $(wcapf_params.shop_loop_container).html(shop_loop.html());
                } else if (not_found.length) {
                    $(wcapf_params.shop_loop_container).html(not_found.html());
                }
            }
        }

        // reinitialize ordering
        wcapfInitOrder();

        // reinitialize dropdown filter
        wcapfDropDownFilter();

        // run scripts after shop loop undated
        if (typeof wcapf_params.custom_scripts !== 'undefined' && wcapf_params.custom_scripts.length > 0) {
            eval(wcapf_params.custom_scripts);
        }
    });
}

// URL Parser
wcapfGetUrlVars = function(url) {
    var vars = {}, hash;

    if (typeof url == 'undefined') {
        url = window.location.href;
    } else {
        url = url;
    }

    // THIS ONE DONT WORK - FROM THE ORIGINAL PLUGIN !!!! 
    // var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    // for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        // hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        // vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    // }
    // return vars;
    
    // THIS PART WORKS - FROM https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727153
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
        
    return vars;
}

// if current page is greater than 1 then we should set it to 1
// every time we add new query to URL to prevent page not found error.
wcapfFixPagination = function() {
    var url = window.location.href,
        params = wcapfGetUrlVars(url);

    if (current_page = parseInt(url.replace(/.+\/page\/([0-9]+)+/, "$1"))) {
        if (current_page > 1) {
            url = url.replace(/page\/([0-9]+)/, 'page/1');
        }
    }
    else if(typeof params['paged'] != 'undefined') {
        current_page = parseInt(params['paged']);
        if (current_page > 1) {
            url = url.replace('paged=' + current_page, 'paged=1');
        }
    }

    return url;
}

// update query string for categories, meta etc..
wcapfUpdateQueryStringParameter = function(key, value, push_history, url) {
    if (typeof push_history === 'undefined') {
        push_history = true;
    }

    if (typeof url === 'undefined') {
        url = wcapfFixPagination();
    }

    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i"),
        separator = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?",
        url_with_query;
    
    if (url.match(re)) {
        url_with_query = url.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
    }
    else {
        url_with_query = url + separator + key + "=" + value;
    }

    if (push_history === true) {
        return history.pushState({}, '', url_with_query);
    } else {
        return url_with_query;
    }
}

// remove parameter from url
wcapfRemoveQueryStringParameter = function(filter_key, url) {
    if (typeof url === 'undefined') {
        url = wcapfFixPagination();
    }

    var params = wcapfGetUrlVars(url),
        count_params = Object.keys(params).length,
        start_position = url.indexOf('?'),
        param_position = url.indexOf(filter_key),
        clean_url,
        clean_query;

    if (count_params > 1) {
        if ((param_position - start_position) > 1) {
            clean_url = url.replace('&' + filter_key + '=' + params[filter_key], '');
        } else {
            clean_url = url.replace(filter_key + '=' + params[filter_key] + '&', '');
        }

        var params = clean_url.split('?');
        clean_query = '?' + params[1];
    } else {
        clean_query = url.replace('?' + filter_key + '=' + params[filter_key], '');
    }

    return clean_query;
}

// add filter if not exists else remove filter
wcapfSingleFilter = function(filter_key, filter_val) {
    var params = wcapfGetUrlVars(),
        query;

    if (typeof params[filter_key] !== 'undefined' && params[filter_key] == filter_val) {
        query = wcapfRemoveQueryStringParameter(filter_key);
    } else {
        query = wcapfUpdateQueryStringParameter(filter_key, filter_val, false);
    }

    // update url
    history.pushState({}, '', query);
    
    // filter products
    wcapfFilterProducts();
}

// take the key and value and make query
wcapfMakeParameters = function(filter_key, filter_val, url) {
    var params,
        next_vals,
        empty_val = false;

    if (typeof url !== 'undefined') {
        params = wcapfGetUrlVars(url);
    } else {
        params = wcapfGetUrlVars();
    }

    if (typeof params[filter_key] != 'undefined') {
        var prev_vals = params[filter_key],
            prev_vals_array = prev_vals.split(',');
        
        if (prev_vals.length > 0) {
            var found = jQuery.inArray(filter_val, prev_vals_array);

            if (found >= 0) {
                // Element was found, remove it.
                prev_vals_array.splice(found, 1);

                if (prev_vals_array.length == 0) {
                    empty_val = true;
                }
            } else {
                // Element was not found, add it.
                prev_vals_array.push(filter_val);
            }

            if (prev_vals_array.length > 1) {
                next_vals = prev_vals_array.join(',');
            } else {
                next_vals = prev_vals_array;
            }
        } else {
            next_vals = filter_val;
        }
    } else {
        next_vals = filter_val;
    }

    // update url and query string
    if (empty_val == false) {
        wcapfUpdateQueryStringParameter(filter_key, next_vals);
    } else {
        var query = wcapfRemoveQueryStringParameter(filter_key);
        history.pushState({}, '', query);
    }

    // filter products
    wcapfFilterProducts();
}

// handle the filter request
$('.wcapf-ajax-term-filter').not('.wcapf-price-filter-widget').on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this),
        filter_key = element.attr('data-key'),
        filter_val = element.attr('data-value'),
        enable_multiple_filter = element.attr('data-multiple-filter');

    if (enable_multiple_filter == true) {
        wcapfMakeParameters(filter_key, filter_val);
    } else {
        wcapfSingleFilter(filter_key, filter_val);
    }

});

// handle the filter request for price filter display type list
$('.wcapf-price-filter-widget.wcapf-ajax-term-filter').on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this),
        filter_key_min = element.attr('data-key-min'),
        filter_val_min = element.attr('data-value-min'),
        filter_key_max = element.attr('data-key-max'),
        filter_val_max = element.attr('data-value-max'),
        query;

    if (element.parent().hasClass('chosen')) {
        query = wcapfRemoveQueryStringParameter(filter_key_min);
        query = wcapfRemoveQueryStringParameter(filter_key_max, query);

        if (query == '') {
            query = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        }

        history.pushState({}, '', query);
    } else {
        query = wcapfUpdateQueryStringParameter(filter_key_min, filter_val_min, false);
        query = wcapfUpdateQueryStringParameter(filter_key_max, filter_val_max, true, query);
    }

    // filter products
    wcapfFilterProducts();
});

// handle the pagination request
if (wcapf_params.pagination_container.length > 0) {
    var holder = wcapf_params.pagination_container + ' a';

    $(document).on('click', holder, function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var location = $(this).attr('href');
        history.pushState({}, '', location);
        
        // filter products
        wcapfFilterProducts();
    });
}

// history back and forward request handling
$(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
    // filter products
    wcapfFilterProducts();
});

// ordering
wcapfInitOrder = function() {
    if (typeof wcapf_params.sorting_control !== 'undefined' && wcapf_params.sorting_control.length && wcapf_params.sorting_control == true) {
        $('.wcapf-before-products').find('.woocommerce-ordering').each(function(index) {
            $(this).on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            $(this).on('change', 'select.orderby', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var order = $(this).val(),
                    filter_key = 'orderby';

                // change url
                wcapfUpdateQueryStringParameter(filter_key, order);

                // filter products
                wcapfFilterProducts();
            });
        });
    }
}

// init ordering
wcapfInitOrder();

// remove active filters
$(document).on('click', '.wcapf-active-filters a:not(.reset)', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this),
        filter_key = element.attr('data-key'),
        filter_val = element.attr('data-value');

    if (typeof filter_val === 'undefined') {
        var query = wcapfRemoveQueryStringParameter(filter_key);
        history.pushState({}, '', query);

        // price slider
        if ($('#wcapf-noui-slider').length && jQuery().noUiSlider) {
            var priceSlider = document.getElementById('wcapf-noui-slider'),
                min_val = parseInt($(priceSlider).attr('data-min')),
                max_val = parseInt($(priceSlider).attr('data-max'));

            if (min_val && max_val) {
                if (filter_key === 'min-price') {
                    priceSlider.noUiSlider.set([min_val, null]);
                } else if (filter_key === 'max-price') {
                    priceSlider.noUiSlider.set([null, max_val]);
                }
            }
        }

        // filter products
        wcapfFilterProducts();
    } else {
        wcapfMakeParameters(filter_key, filter_val);
    }
});

// clear all filters
$(document).on('click', '.wcapf-active-filters a.reset', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var location = $(this).attr('data-location');
    history.pushState({}, '', location);

    // filter products
    wcapfFilterProducts();
});

// dispaly type dropdown
function formatState(state) {
    var depth = $(state.element).attr('data-depth'),
        $state = $('<span class="depth depth-' + depth + '">' + state.text + '</span>');
    
    return $state;
}

wcapfDropDownFilter = function() {
    if ($('.wcapf-select2-single').length) {
        $('.wcapf-select2-single').select2({
            templateResult: formatState,
            minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
            allowClear: true
        });
    }

    if ($('.wcapf-select2-multiple').length) {
        $('.wcapf-select2-multiple').select2({
            templateResult: formatState,
        });
    }

    $('.select2-dropdown').css('display', 'none');
}

// initialize dropdown filter
wcapfDropDownFilter();

$(document).on('change', '.wcapf-select2', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var filter_key = $(this).attr('name'),
        filter_val = $(this).val();

    if (!filter_val) {
        var query = wcapfRemoveQueryStringParameter(filter_key);
        history.pushState({}, '', query);
    } else {
        filter_val = filter_val.toString();
        wcapfUpdateQueryStringParameter(filter_key, filter_val);
    }

    // filter products
    wcapfFilterProducts();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The soution was to add `event.stopPropagation();` in addition to the `event.preventDefault();` function to the following part of the code:

```
    // handle the filter request
$('.wcapf-ajax-term-filter').not('.wcapf-price-filter-widget').on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation(); // Added to solve the problem!
    var element = $(this),
        filter_key = element.attr('data-key'),
        filter_val = element.attr('data-value'),
        enable_multiple_filter = element.attr('data-multiple-filter');

    if (enable_multiple_filter == true) {
        wcapfMakeParameters(filter_key, filter_val);
    } else {
        wcapfSingleFilter(filter_key, filter_val);
    }

});
```