# HTML anchor and query string

Tags: html, email, anchor, query-string, hyperlink

Is it possible to do something like the URL below?

```
myurl.co.uk/#myAnchor?myQry=this
```

I'm trying to pass tracking codes while also being able to have multiple links from an email go to relevant parts of my page.

This currently seems to do nothing as it is. Is it actually possible.

Comment: Related: *[Proper URL forming with a query string and an anchor hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682952/)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query goes before the anchor, so:

```
http://example.com/page.php?parameter=value#anchor
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the query always comes before any anchors, here is the solution for this if required.

One solution for this could be to use [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) HTACCESS and declare #myAnchor in rewrite rules. Then you can use something like this:

```
myurl.co.uk/#myAnchor?myQry=this
```

But please remember that in the htaccess the `#` is also used for commenting so you will have to escape it with a rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this seems a little over complicated for what I need to simply come from an email and use a little javascript for analytics

Comment: Thannks dear, I though if it is required for you then this can be the solution.