# jqm 1.4.2 - Passing Passing URL Parameters with Hash

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, query-string

Currently having trouble navigating to a page AND passing query string parameters in jQueryMobile.

I am using a single html document with multiple "page" elements in the DOM.  Page navigation is working as expected, however query string parameters seem to be filtered out...

Listview Example:

```
<li class="ui-first-child"><a href="#venue?id=hello"...
```

The list item contains an 'id' parameter however when clicked on url resolves to

```
www.domain.com/index.html#venue
```

I have had a look at the below thread.  I did suspect that it could be the order in which i was including the parameters but "?id=hello#venue" has the same result!

[Proper URL forming with Query String and Anchor Hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682952/proper-url-forming-with-query-string-and-anchor-hashtag)

Comment: Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682952/proper-url-forming-with-query-string-and-anchor-hashtag

This is almost a duplicate.

Comment: I saw that thread but that didn't help me either.  "?id=hello#venue" has the same result...  Just in case you didn't notice, i am using jQuerymobile which handles navigation its own way.  Version 1.4.2.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the jqm

Comment: Do you need to know any other details?  I'm stumped as to why this is happening, i have even inspected the URL when the "pagecontainerbeforeshow" gets fired and that too doesn't include parameters..

Comment: Yeah more context of what you are doing or have so far would be nice. Tough to delve into with just that snippet or possibly I could be running low on caffeine at this time.