# Using an anchor tag with URL parameters to the same page URL

Tags: html, anchor, url-parameters

I am trying to use page anchors within a URL that also contains parameters, but that links to the same URL (with a slightly different parameter set). But all that is happening, when they are clicked, is the page simply scrolls to the anchor point without reloading.

I have a search feature which returns a visitor's search results on "search.php". Let’s say they have 100 search results and I display 10 at a time (per page). At the bottom of file *search.php* I have the page numbers (1 to 10) which link to *search.php*, but with a different page parameter set (the same search parameters though). Each link is basically "search.php?parameter1=this&parameter2=that&page=2#anchor"

I’ve tried placing the anchor before the parameters and I have tried using full URLs (http://www.url.com/search.php...) rather than local, but nothing seems to work. Is it even possible?

Comment: Please provide a code example. You need to set the href of your link accordingly: <a href="search.php?parameter1=this&{...}#anchor"> should work. You will either need a server-side or a client-side script to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure a code example will help. Its just a basic <a> link. I dont have any issues with the script or search results. The script all works fine, the page links work fine but when I add the #anchor it stops actually linking anywhere and just ignores everything but the anchor. If I remove the anchor everything is great but I want to scroll down slightly so the user doesn't have to on every search results page.

Comment: Related: [An answer to *Proper URL forming with a query string and an anchor hashtag*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682952/proper-url-forming-with-a-query-string-and-an-anchor-hashtag/48728926#48728926)