# Python Requests passes params before the end of the URL

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using requests in Python in order to get some data from a website, but there are multiple pages. They are accessible by modifying the URL parameter `page=x`.
However by using GET like this :

```
r = requests.get(page, params={'sort':0, 'perPage':40, 'page':i})
```

the parameters are placed before the end of the URL, as `print(r.url)` shows :

```
link.html?sort=0&perPage=40&page=1#/
```

instead of

```
link.html#/?sort=0&perPage=40&page=1
(see the "#/" placement)
```

Moreover, it seems that I can't pass the direct URL in the GET to access the other pages like this :

```
page_initial = "link.html#/
for i in range(1,50):
    page = page_initial+"?sort=0&perPage=40&page={}".format(i)
    r = requests.get(page)
    ...
```

This always returns the content of the first page again.

Am I missing something or am I using this wrongly ?

Comment: Everything after the # is only interpreted by the browser, not the server (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997420/what-are-fragment-urls-and-why-to-use-them), so requests is helping you. If you see parameters after the # when you browse this page, that means that they are being handled by javascript and requests can't help you, and you'll need to switch to Selenium.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682952/proper-url-forming-with-query-string-and-anchor-hashtag

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks a lot