# URL with both #anchor tag and query parameters

Tags: html, web, url

Is there a way we can add both the # tag and a query parameter to a URL?

E.g.: **[www.website.com/some_vanity#some_id?source_id=someID&source_pw=somePW](http://www.website.com/some_vanity#some_id?source_id=someID&source_pw=somePW)**

[www.website.com/some_vanity#some_id](http://www.website.com/some_vanity#some_id) --> this one will navigate the page to a particular section in that page

Comment: need to swap the order

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682952/proper-url-forming-with-query-string-and-anchor-hashtag

Answer (score 1):

The format for query strings is `url?query=val#anchor`. So you just need to swap the order of your query parameters and anchor.

For your example, this would work:

[www.website.com/some_vanity?source_id=someID&source_pw=somePW#some_id](http://www.website.com/some_vanity?source_id=someID&source_pw=somePW#some_id)