# HashRouter appending queryParameters to before the pathname

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am implementing a routing mechanism using HashRouters, where I have configured my application like this:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter basename="/">
                <NavigationBar />
                <Routes />
                <Footer />
             </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

And the Routes are configured like this:

```
const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LogIn} />
            <Route exact path="/account" component={Account} />
            <Route exact path="*" component={Error404} />
        </Switch>
    );
};
```

While everything is working fine, I have an API call to make where, the backend API appends a QueryParameter to the URL which I am passing.

For example,

```
const baseReturnUrl = window.location.href;
const returnUrl = baseReturnUrl + '/#/account' // This should go to account page 
let response = await fetch(returnUrl); // Here is the API call which will return to the page provided after successful call
```

Ideally the URL after API call should be like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4321/#/account?parameter=abcdef
```

But it is actually returning something like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4321/?parameter=abcdef#/account
```

Which looks a bit odd. Also is there an option to omit the hash in the HashRouter, to look something like this: `http://0.0.0.0:4321/` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:4321/#/`
I have tried to replicate a codesandbox, but I am unable to replicate the API call model.

Comment: As per [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682952/proper-url-forming-with-a-query-string-and-an-anchor-hashtag), your URL is formatted correctly, even though it does look unusual. Additionally, you may omit the root-level hash if you're linking directly to the root page.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen, the fragment goes after the query: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax

Comment: Okay, is there a way in React to omit this?
I did not knew about thsi

Comment: What do you mean "omit" it? If you want to use the fragment for routing, that's what you'll get.